# button with two functions using Booleans?

Tags: java, android, button, boolean

I just started a new app project but I'm having a problem. I would like to have a Button in android that, once pressed, switches to a different function when pressed again, using Booleans. In case you need what context, I'm making a start/stop button for a `CountDownTimer`. I want to know if this is just a simple concept that's flying over my head, or if it's an actual complicated process. Thanks!

**NOTE: This is not talking about handling the button if it is long pressed. It's talking about handling the button the first time it's pressed, and the second time it's pressed.**

Here's my code:

```
TextView timerText;
CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
Button controlButton;
boolean timerisActive;

public void controlClick(View view) {

        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timerTime + 100, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                Long minutes = millisUntilFinished / 1000 / 60;
                Long seconds = millisUntilFinished / 1000 - minutes * 60;
                String secondString = seconds.toString();
                String minuteString = minutes.toString();
                if (seconds <= 9) {
                    secondString = "0" + secondString;
                }
                timerText.setText(minuteString + ":" + secondString);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                timerText.setText("0:00");
            }

        }.start();
        if(timerisActive = true){
            countDownTimer.cancel();
            timerText.setText("0:00");
        }
        controlButton.setText("Stop");

    }
```

Comment: No, the above question talks about different action on click and long click, not about handling click in different states.

Comment: Thank you Antony. I edited the question clarifying this. Hopefully this will be unmarked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this create a new `boolean` variable like this

```
 boolean isfirstTime = true;
```

than make check when use click first time or second time based on that boolean

make your `button.setOnClickListener` like below code

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
       if (isfirstTime) {
           // call here first time action
           isfirstTime=false;
       }else {
          // call here second time action
         // make isfirstTime = true; 
         // if you want to perform again first time action after second time use press the button
       }


     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach is, you first create an interface of the action like:

```
interface ButtonAction {
    void perform();
}
```

Then you create an array of actions that would perform in sucession. With an array of size two give you a toggling action set, while any size larger would give you flexiblity of a switching action set.

```
private ButtonAction[] allButtonActions = ... // Create the concrete action implementations.
```

And keep an index of the active action:

```
private int activeActionIndex = 0;
```

Then in the button click event handler:

```
allButtonActions[activeActionIndex].perform();

// Perform next action at next click.
activeActionIndex++;

// Wrap to first action if reached last action already.
if (activeActionIndex >= allButtonActions.length) {
    activeActionIndex = 0;
}
```